# commenting issue awesome Window manager

Tags: linux, lua, awesome-wm

I'm trying to create a startup-run daemon client for my emacs. The Lua file identifies "--" as a comment

`"usr/bin/emacs --daemon"`

my rc.lua file thinks "--daemon" was a comment any idea guys?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure all the quotes are in the right place? This is not how lua behaves:

```lua
# /usr/bin/lua
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> s = "foo --bar" --baz
> print(s)
foo --bar
>
```

In your example, you wrote `usr/bin/emacs` instead of `/usr/bin/emacs`. Maybe this is the problem?